# Activity noHistory="true" doesn't work when screen locked

Tags: android, android-activity

I've set `noHistory="true"` for the `Activity` on the manifest. The expected result is when the user navigates away from `Activity` and it's no longer visible on screen the activity will be finished.

This works fine when i navigate to different application by pressing home button and coming back to Activity recreates as expected. But when the `Activity` is visible , and if the screen locked,and  unlocked back `resumes the activity` . I want the `Activity` to recreate or just not show up, let the user launch the app again.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the `Activity` to recreate or just not show up, let the user
>   launch the app again.

I believe you can handle ***if the screen is locked***, then do your stuffs like killing the app.Seems like when the user is locking the screen, `Activity` is going in `onPause();` method.

**Here is the logcat:**

```
02-18 20:27:23.621 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onCreate() event
02-18 20:27:23.621 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onStart() event
02-18 20:27:23.626 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onResume() event
02-18 20:27:27.156 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onPause() event
02-18 20:27:27.161 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onStop() event
02-18 20:27:36.866 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onRestart() event
02-18 20:27:36.866 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onStart() event
02-18 20:27:36.881 22250-22250/com.client.stackoveflow E/LifeCycleEvents: In the onResume() event
```

So, kill the app/or do your stuffs when user locked the screen like this in `onPause();` method:

```
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.e(tag, "In the onPause() event");
        // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn(); // deprecated, but you can use isInteractive too

        if (!isScreenOn) {

            finish();  // or do your stuffs
        }

    }
```

Then, if the user locked the screen, App will be finished and needs to opening it again.